# What's the meaning of this Idiom? "Slippery Slope"

Tags: idioms

She realized he was on the **slippery slope** towards a life of
crime.

Help me to figure out the meaning of that Idiom.

Some other example can help me most.

Comment: Did you try to look up what "[slippery slope](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slippery%20slope)" means?

Answer (score 2):

Imagine the "**slippery slope**" in its literal sense, it would be something like a hill covered in ice.

"She realized he was on the slippery slope towards a life of crime."

She realized he was on a hill covered in ice and if he took a step, he would slip and fall down the hill torwards a life of crime with basically no chance of stopping before reaching the bottom.

The basic meaning is that "he" is in a dangerous position (the "slippery slope") and a single misstep would have large consequences.